# Parent class using default constructor; child class' destructor is unexpectedly called

Tags: c++, c++11

I had a scenario in C++ that calls the child's destructor in a case where I didn't expect it. A minimal repro is below:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Parent {
public:
};

class Child : public Parent {
    public:
    ~Child() {
        printf("Got here\n");
    }
};

int 
main()
{
    shared_ptr<Parent> x(new Child);
}
```

Usually something like this is a bug. The developer intends that the child destructor is called, and the correct action would be to insert into the parent an empty virtual destructor. However, to my shock, both G++ 4.4.7 (yeah, I know it's old) and clang 3.4.2 compile this such that the child destructor *is* called.

Does this conform to the standard?

Comment: @chris yeah I checked, it does that thing, not sure that it's useful at all.

Comment: @n.m., Can't say I've personally had a need for it, but it's a nice thing to have when you do.

Comment: @n.m. It's useful because you can use `shared_ptr<Base>` to manage derived objects, without the overhead of a virtual destructor

Comment: @M.M but with the overhead of a custom deleter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well even if `shared_ptr` didn't have special magic, `delete`ing by parent pointer with non-virtual destructor is just undefined behavior so the results (of calling the child destructor) would definitely be conforming.

But in this case `shared_ptr` "remembers" the type of the original object you passed into it and destroys it by child pointer (through its stored deleter).

Comment: Um, doesn't the stored deleter use the template type and not the type used to create it with?

Comment: No, roughly it stores a `std::function` (or equivalent) to `deleter<U>` where `U` is the constructor's parameter type, not the `shared_ptr` template type. It even works on `shared_ptr<void>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

A unique ptr would screw up here.  But shared ptr does some "magic" here.

`shared_ptr<T> has two things they manage; the`T*` and the reference counting block.

The reference counting block contains two `atomic<std::size_t>`s, one for strong references and one for weak references, and a type-erased deleter.  This `std::function`-like type-erased deleter *remembers* how to delete the thing you own.

When you construct any `shared_ptr` with a `U*u`, it by default stores `[u]{std::default_delete<U>{}(u);}` in that deleter.

In effect, it remembers how to delete the object based on the type passed in.

`shared_ptr` is exceedingly flexible.

You can pass in a custom deleter to replace the default one, you can use the aliasing constructor to split the reference counting block used from the `T*` stored, you can use `make_shared` to allocate the reference counting block and a `T` in the same memory allocation.

The overhead of the reference counting block is why it stores the deleter; it wasn't viewed as overly expensive, given that we needed the block anyhow.  In comparison, `unique_ptr` by default does no such thing; you have to explicitly add a deleter, and you'd have to manage all of the fancy tricks that shared_ptr does for you by default if you wanted them.  `unique_ptr` has basically zero overhead over a raw owning pointer; `shared_ptr` has noticable overhead, but small compared to memory allocation overhead usually.